# How to suppress warning when deleting thumbs.db?

Tags: windows

There is quite a lot of information out there how to disable the creation of the thumbs.db files that store thumbnail info for images within a given folder. 
I personally have no problem with the thumbs.db file as they are hidden. But what bothers me greatly is that Windows still gives a warning about deletion of such files even when I am deleting the entire folder it is in. `<vent>`Why would a user want to preserve the thumbnail info in a folder if they desire to delete the entire folder? `</vent>`

With that in mind, is there any conceivable way to disable such warnings?

Comment: For instance- since this behavior is due to thumbs.db being considered a system file, can I 'demote' them to a more worldly status?

Comment: Those warnings appear whenever there's at least one file with the System attribute set. The easiest way to bypass them is to use the command-line interface: `rd /s /q "X:\some\folder"`

Comment: Yes, it's kind of ironic that Windows lets you delete "PreciousFamilyPhoto.jpg" and "UnrecoverableManuscript.docx" without a problem (which is fine, BTW), but yells "OMG, you are about to delete thumbs.db, are you really, really sure?". I guess the solution would be to have some "non-vital system (cache) file" attribute, but only Microsoft can implement that.

Comment: If `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` option in Folder Options is not checked, you'll get warnings when deleting folders that contain images.